# addplot3 ignoring me - edited

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

**Edited** to correct the problem identified by Eduardo, and to change the placement of the domain options -- I realized they were in the wrong place. However, while I get a 3D frame, the plot is 2D.

Original: When I compile the following code I get an empty 2D box with tick marks from 0 to 1 (by tenths) on both axes despite the domain options and addplot3 completely ignores the data table. Here's the code (no need for output, it's just a box):

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
    ] 
    \addplot3 [
    domain = -1:1,
    domain y = -1:1,
    surf]
    table {
-1  -1              0.108950496
-0.9    -0.9        0.12366302
-0.8    -0.8        0.138503226
-0.7    -0.7        0.153069738
-0.6    -0.6        0.166927617
-0.5    -0.5        0.179629001
-0.4    -0.4        0.190736638
-0.3    -0.3        0.199848641
-0.2    -0.2        0.206622533
-0.1    -0.1        0.210796585
0   0       0.212206591
0.1 0.1     0.210796585
0.2 0.2     0.206622533
0.3 0.3     0.199848641
0.4 0.4     0.190736638
0.5 0.5     0.179629001
0.6 0.6     0.166927617
0.7 0.7     0.153069738
0.8 0.8     0.138503226
0.9 0.9     0.12366302
1   1       0.108950496
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hoped to get a 3D surface. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood anything, but the x/y coordinates you are using to describe your plot are all in the same line in the xy plane (which is x = y), right? Perharps to obtain a surface you would need points outside this line?

Comment: Also, although it should be possible, I believe it would be easier to use a plot with a mathematical expression, like this: https://pgfplots.net/fill-space-3d/ . Is your data coming from an expression?

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva. Thank you for weighing in again. Yes, the x and y values are the same, but since x and y are orthogonal I didn't think that would be a problem. It 's clear that I don't understand how pgfplots views the world. The plot should be of a bivariate  standard normal distribution. I assumed having the same points along the x and y axes would be fine. The formula is messy, as no doubt you know. It was easier to generate the f(x,y) values outside and just paste them. Am I to understand from your question that I need to have a differ set of points for x and y?

Comment: Clarification. Standard biraviate  normal on a grid x = -1 to 1 and y = -1 to 1 by increments of 0.1 in both dimensions. I thought that's what I gave it.

Comment: By messy I mean that with my poor eyesight it is way too easy to mis-key when  entering a long formula. It is easier for me to do it in something like Excel where I can break it up into pieces and then add them. As you might have guessed from my silly mistake in the beginning. my eyesight is not that great.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I think I understand what you mean. I will edit my answer, see if it outputs what you expect!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139112/discussion-between-eduardo-alves-da-silva-and-tonyk).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace the command addplot3 with \addplot3

**Edit**: Based on TonyK edit, I believe using an expression instead of the table plot does the job.

Based on TonyK's comment on the post, this should be the correct input:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
    mesh/cols=11,
    mesh/rows=11
    ] 
    \addplot3 [domain = -1:1,
    domain y = -1:1,
    surf] {exp((-x^2 -y^2)/2)/(2*pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Correct output (hopefully)]

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something stupid, but lately I can stare at "stupid" all day and not see it. There was no compiler error to signal I'd done something silly.

Comment: Thanks again. I added the \ and, as noted above, I moved the domain options.But  pgfplots still seems to be ignoring the second domain.

Comment: You did it and I am very appreciative. I am a user of this technology, not a practitioner and I am happy to take this solution to my problem. But suppose I want an N(1,2) with an N(2,3) with cov(0.7), what do I do then? I guess I can modify the mathematical expression, but I am still left with 'what did I do wrong.' in this simpler case. Also, mesh / col ? that is new to me. I should say that you have already answered my question and you are done. Perhaps I need to read more of the manual. Thanks again.